# Why does this recursive function work like this?

Tags: php, algorithm, recursion, computer-science

I am trying to learn recursion and have written a function that takes a number and count it down to zero and then count it up to the original number again, the function works, but what I don't understand is why it works as it does. I understnad why the first print after the else statement prints: "5 4 3 2 1" and then the number is 0 and the if statement prints: "0". It is after this scenario I don't understand since now the function enters the second print after the else statement and prints: "1 2 3 4 5" which is very strange to me. I would really appreciate if someone could explain this to me.

```
<?php
function rec_downandup($num){
    if($num == 0){
        print '0 ';
    }else{
        print $num.' ';
        rec_downandup($num-1);
        print $num.' ';
    }
}
rec_downandup(5);
?>
```

**Output**

```
5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Try to trace the execution by hand.

Comment: Well, the 5 would go through and get printed twice... but between that the 4 would go through and get printed twice... but between that the 3 would go through and get printed twice... etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you take a closer look, it should become clear.

```
print $num.' ';
rec_downandup($num-1);
print $num.' ';
```

For your first input, you will get

```
print 5.' ';
rec_downandup(4);
print 5.' ';
```

and after that call it is

```
print 5.' ';
print 4.' ';
rec_downandup(3);
print 4.' ';
print 5.' ';
```

So it appears the functions counts down and up, but actually it just counts down and places each number twice - the second time in reverse order so it appears to be counting up.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @kingero is spot on, it explains exactly what is happening. If you want to have a straight countdown you would do this -

```
function rec_downandup($num){
    if($num == 0){
        print '0 ';
    }else{
        echo $num;
        $num = rec_downandup($num-1); // you can do this without the variable assignment, it just seems neater this way.
    }
}
rec_downandup(5);
```

Comment: variable assignment doesn't make any sense to me here, the function doesn't even return anything... and even if it did it wouldn't matter because the scope would expire as soon as its done

Comment: I agree @smerny, it is just a readability thing which is why I commented the code.

Answer (score 0):

Each time the `re_downandup()` function is called, the parameter `$num` takes the value passed to the function and it will keep that value until the function ends in its last closing brace.

Also important to understand is that in presence of a recursive call to the function, the execution flow continues in this call, this is why the second `print` won't happen until the execution returns from said recursive call.

So lets take this:

```
print $num.' ';
rec_downandup($num-1);
print $num.' ';
```

The first `print $num` will print the number, then the execution flow will continue in the new call to the function, which will show the variable's value minus one. This will continue to occur recursively until `$num` reaches zero.

When the recursion breaking condition `$num == 0` is given, the function will "be allowed" to continue until the end; so each recursive call will return, and that is when the second `print $num` will begin to execute, for that is what happens when the execution flow of your program returns from `rec_downandup()`.

The value printed in this case will be whatever value the `$num` variable had when the recursive call was triggered.